# Завершение работы скрипта после прерывания

Tags: прерывания, php

Не могу понять, после того как я закрываю скрипт он продолжает создавать файлы хотя такого быть не должно, тестирую на Open Server

```
<?php
  $limit = 60;
  $time = time();
  ignore_user_abort(0);
  set_time_limit($limit+10);
  while(time()-$time < $limit){
    fopen(time().'.txt', 'w');
    sleep(1);
  }
?>
```

Comment: почему нет? От того что вы закрыли браузер, сервер не прекратит выполнение цикла.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, какой конечной цели Вы хотите добиться этим скриптом?

Answer (score 1):

Если из браузера скрипт закрыть, он все равно продолжит свою работу, пока не выполнит все инструкции. Или вы из консоли закрываете?

Comment: Из браузера, я делаю ajax обновление статуса онлайн на основе открытого соединения, и такая ерунда приносит неудобства

Comment: в таком случае вообще непонятно зачем вам создавать файлы и использовать открытое окно. 

создайте в javascript таймер ( setInterval() ), который с определенной периодичностью (например раз в 2 минуты) будет  стучаться ajax-ом к скрипту, который будет обновлять статус пользователя. Если пользователь не отправлял запросы на роут более чем 2 минуты, он считается оффлайн.

Comment: При закрытии браузера скрипт продолжает выполняться (так как его выполнение происходит непосредственно на сервере) и избежать этого никак нельзя. Я так однажды базу положил, случайно сделав бесконечный цикл для добавление записей в БД, лечится только перезапуском сервера))

Comment: о_О вообще, какой смысл использования бесконечного цикла при добалении записей в бд? объясните пожалуйста. вы же создаете огромную нагрузку на сервер.

Comment: если вам нужно знать, онлайн пользователь или не онлайн - создайте отдельное поле в таблице пользователей - например last_activity. 

В него, после каждого обращения к скрипту записывайте текущее время. Если вам понадобиться узнать, онлайн пользователь или оффлайн, сверьте таймштамп текущего времени и времени в бд. Если оно будет больше 2 минут например, считайте пользователя оффлайн.

Comment: Цикл получился бесконечным по случайности) Мне нужно было разово добавить около сотни записей в бд, ну и в условии вместо "== 100" написал "= 100", что, конечно, сразу заметил, но его уже было не остановить =)
Да, кстати, ТС, объясните смысл скрипта, может найдется альтернативное решение?

Comment: 2 минуты много, у меня онлайн чат, мне надо максимум 4 секунды

Comment: На мой взгляд, инструмент для чата выбран не совсем удачно. Лучше посмотреть в сторону асинхронных вещей, например tornado, gevent, NodeJS и т.п. - для сервера. И использовать web-сокеты и/или другую технологию persistent-соединений  - для клиентской части

Comment: в таком случае используйте вебсокеты. например socket.io и соответственно какое-либо серверное решение (nodeJS например). так как без кучи запросов раз в 4 секунды и нагрузки на клиент и сервер вы не обойдетесь.

Comment: а насчет случайности в цикле - используйте for и таких проблем у вас не возникнет =)